# In Germany, Tax class changed to 3 but I am still getting as tax class 1

Tags: income-tax, germany

In Germany, Tax class changed to 3 two month back but I am still getting salary as tax class 1. How much transition time generally take for class transaction to reflect my monthly salary.

Comment: Do you have already the confirmation letter from "Finanzamt"?

Comment: did you give that information to your employer? I think it should not take long - but either way you can get it back with the tax return next year retroactive for the whole year

Answer (score 2):

This is purely an issue with your employeer,so quite hard to give an exact figurehere. Anything above 2 months, contact HR.

Answer (score 1):

Some employers just query the Elstam database at the beginning of the year. If you have changes during the year, you have to tell them about the update so they can request your Elstam file again.

But don't worry too much about it. If you file your taxes, everything will be corrected by the Finanzamt so in your case you will probably get a bigger tax return than you are used to.